# Autoloader does not seem to be updating (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, autoload

I'm new to PHP Laravel. I've added a package using composer: `composer require djchen/oauth2-fitbit`. It seems that my composer.json did not update the autoloader as i keep getting the following error:

`Fatal error: Class 'djchen\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Fitbit' not found in xxx on line 5`.

this is what line 5 looks like:

```
use djchen\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Fitbit;
$provider = new Fitbit([ // line 5
```

Here is my composer.json (necessary bits)

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "vcs",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "djchen/oauth2-fitbit": "^1.0",
    "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "djchen\\OAuth2\\Client\\": "src/" // added manually - still does not work
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/",
    }
},
```

I've done my research and i've tried composer install, composer update and composer dump-autoload. None of these worked. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I just installed the package and created a sample object and it worked fine. You don't need to add that bit in the composer.json, composer auto loads the classes based on the package composer.json file. You should remove the composer.json changes and reinstall the package once. You don't need to do anything else. Composer on install will update it's autoloader.

Comment: Maybe also try `php artisan optimize --force`

Comment: Have you tried `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? You could check in `vendor/composer`how the current autoloader files look like

Answer (score 3):

Let's go with the nuclear solution here, your autoload file probably is cached somewhere.

Run following commands:

```
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan optimize
```

If this doesn't work, try to manually delete all autoload files you can find and run a `composer update`.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question..

I probably should have really emphasised the fact that I'm new to Laravel. I managed to get around this by simply including the autoloader:

```
include('vendor/autoload.php');
```

And also calling composer dump-autoload afterwards.